# Is there an official list of Spanish onomatopoeia?

Tags: rae, dle, recursos, onomatopeyas

An onomatopoeia is a word that represents a sound.

> **[onomatopeya](http://dle.rae.es/?w=onomatopeya)**.
>   Del lat. tardío *onomatopoeia*, y este del gr. *ὀνοματοποιΐα onomatopoiḯa*.
>
> 1. f. Formación de una palabra por imitación del sonido de aquello que designa. Muchas palabras como quiquiriquí han sido formadas por onomatopeya.
> 2. f. Palabra cuya forma fónica imita el sonido de aquello que designa; p. ej., runrún.

The DLE has entries for some of this words, like **[*bum*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=bum)** for the sound of an explosion, or [***zas***](http://dle.rae.es/?w=zas) for the sound of a hit (as debated in a [previous question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22763/13628)), or **[*quiquiriquí*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UvmGIAD)** for the Spanish version of "cock-a-doodle-do!".

The DPD also has an [official list of abbreviations](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice2.html) were one could look up if an abbreviation is accepted. This is because I just can't go and say that *"Prdnte."* means *"Presidente"*. I mean... I could, but no one would understand it, because the official abbreviation is *"Pdte."*.

Likewise, I can't just go and say that *"cracachof"* is the onomatopoeia for a tree cracking and falling into a lake. I could, but I don't think anybody would understand it without explanation.

So my question is: **is there an official list of recognized Spanish onomatopoeic words, like the one the DPD has for abbreviations?**

Comment: Oficial no sé, pero aquí hay una lista hecha por José Martínez de Sousa: http://www.fundeu.es/escribireninternet/tatatachan-95-onomatopeyas/
Y también podemos buscar en el DLE: https://www.google.es/search?q=%22onomat+u%22+site:rae.es&ei=18_pWd2hGOLPgAb2kZvIBA&start=10&sa=N&biw=1489&bih=595

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que por "oficial" te refieres a "incluido en el DLE". Como en otros casos, aquí el [DIRAE](http://dirae.es) viene muy bien. Las voces onomatopéyicas están marcadas como "onomat.". Buscando y filtrando las voces de origen onomatopéyico, y ayudado por la [consulta en Google](https://www.google.es/search?q=%22onomat%20u%22%20site:rae.es&ei=18_pWd2hGOLPgAb2kZvIBA&start=10&sa=N&biw=1489&bih=595) [de blonfu](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22844/is-there-an-official-list-of-spanish-onomatopoeia/22846#comment36675_22844), he dado con la siguiente lista:

- achís (para el estornudo)
- be (para el balido de la cabra, la oveja o el carnero)
- bla (repetida para imitar el ruido del habla ininterrumpida y previsible)
- bum (para ruidos o explosiones)
- cataplum (para ruidos, explosiones o golpes)
- catapum (como "cataplum")
- chinchín (para el sonido de una banda de música, especialmente de los platillos)
- clac (para imitar un sonido seco y de breve duración)
- clic (similar a "clac")
- clo (para imitar el sonido de la gallina clueca)
- cloc (igual que "clo")
- crac (para el ruido de algo que se quiebra)
- cricrí (para imitar el canto del grillo)
- frufrú (para el ruido que produce el roce de la seda o de otra tela semejante)
- fu (para el bufido del gato)
- gluglú (para representar el ruido del agua al sumirse o dejar escapar el aire)
- guau (para el ladrido del perro)
- hin (para el relincho del caballo o del mulo)
- marramao (para el sonido del gato en época de celo)
- miau (para el maullido del gato)
- mu (para el toro y la vaca)
- mua (para el sonido del beso)
- paf (para el ruido que hace alguien o algo al caer o chocar contra algún objeto)
- pío (para el sonido de cualquier ave)
- plof (para el ruido que hace alguien o algo al caer o chocar contra algún objeto)
- quiquiriquí (para el canto del gallo)
- rataplán (para imitar el sonido del tambor)
- tictac (para el ruido acompasado de un reloj)
- tras (para golpes con ruido)
- zis (igual que "zas")
- zas (para el ruido de un golpe)

En esta lista faltarán muchas de las onomatopeyas que se usan cotidianamente para otras cosas. Hay que tener en cuenta que la RAE solo recoge palabras que aparecen en textos escritos, y no en el habla, que suele ser junto con los cómics el mejor medio para transmitir onomatopeyas. Ignoro si la RAE tiene en cuenta los cómics para la elaboración de su diccionario.