# What is the sound of a baby's cry in Spanish?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

What is the sound of a baby's cry in Spanish (i.e., the Spanish equivalent for English's "Waah!" or "Wah!")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this Fundéu list](http://www.fundeu.es/escribireninternet/tatatachan-95-onomatopeyas/), the Spanish onomatopoeia for a crying baby is "bua":

> - llanto de un bebé: *¡bua, bua!*

The official dictionary (the DLE) [does not include it as a word](http://dle.rae.es/?w=bua), though; but that's expected, as explained in the answer to this other question: [Is there an official list of Spanish onomatopoeia?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22844/13628).

Comment: Nor does the _Oxford English Dictionary_ include "Waah!", "Wah!", etc.

Comment: I know in Mexican Spanish at least the word I've heard used sounds like "_¡cuñá! ¡cuñá!_" (I might not be getting the spelling 100% right).

Answer (score 4):

In Chile our onomatopoeia is **¡guaaa!** This is because in the Mapuzungun language (the language of the Mapuche ethnic group), "baby" is called *guagua*, and later its use has been extended to all current Spanish speech, even in formal and cultured situations.

(I never thought that elsewhere the onomatopoeia was different, consequently I am very surprised to read here that the standard form is *buaaa*. In Chile, this form seems closer to the scare.)

Comment: @Rodrigo, guagua (wawa in Mapudungun) actually comes from Quechua and it's not clear if were the Spaniards who took that word into the Mapuche people, or were the Incas themselves who introduce it into Mapudungun previously.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is an "onomatopoeia".

You can find a little feedback here over the different onomatopoeias for the crying sound:

https://www.proz.com/kudoz/english_to_spanish/poetry_literature/1507440-la_onomatopeya_del_llanto.html

- buu/ buaa
- bua / buah / buahhh
- snif snif
- guaaa

Comment: De ellas, yo destacaría "buaa", es prácticamente la única que he oído.

Comment: Remember that it's OK to link other pages, but it's mandatory to copy here the most relevant parts. So the answer will always be here even if the linked page changes or disappears.

Comment: Yes, of course I'm looking for _onomatopeyas_, but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Geremia, I even gave you a list of Reviewed site of the onomatopoeias used, if you want to know if the sound have a name, the I can tell you, it does not , you only translate it to : "el llanto de un bebe", 
so I don't really understand what you are looking for.