# ¿Existen nombres para los movimientos realizados por el cuerpo?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Así como los sonidos tienen movimientos llamados "onomatopeyas", ¿existen nombres para los movimientos realizados por el cuerpo?

Por ejemplo:

> Alzar el puño en señal de victoria.

hay uno en concreto que ni siquiera sé como describirlo, pero es más o menos así:

> "Golpearse el costado con brazo en un movimento que inicia con el brazo extendido hacia adelante deslizando el brazo bruscamente hacia abajo y atras, manteniendo el antebrazo apuntando hacia adelante, terminado con el codo a la altura de las costillas", normalmente utilizado de manera sutil despues de haber conseguido un exito, mas no necesariamente una victoria.

Comment: [¿Algo así?](https://goo.gl/images/sJZjJZ)

Comment: @Charlie Exactamente eso !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atendiendo al [comentario de Gustavson](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23346/existen-nombres-para-los-movimientos-realizados-por-el-cuerpo/23581#comment37673_23348), vamos a suponer que la pregunta es esta:

> *Así como existe una clase de palabras llamadas "onomatopeyas" que definen sonidos, ¿existe otra clase similar de palabras que definan movimientos realizados por el cuerpo?*

La cuestión es que, si para los sonidos existe una clase de palabras especial, es porque la relación entre sonidos y palabras es especial.

No hay absolutamente nada en la secuencia de sonidos `/a/ /r/ /b/ /o/ /l/` que recuerde ni remotamente a un árbol; sin embargo, todos los que entienden español identifican esa secuencia de sonidos con el concepto "árbol".
Y así, usamos los sonidos, no por su propio sonido, sino para transmitir conceptos abstractos mediante palabras.

Ahora bien, a veces lo que queremos transmitir no es un concepto abstracto, sino un sonido en sí mismo: el maullido de un gato, el crujir de una rama al romperse, la explosión de un volcán. El sonido lo podemos imitar sin mucho problema, pero para transmitirlo necesitamos convertirlo en una palabra.

No hay nada en la secuencia de letras `M I A U` que se parezca en nada a un gato, y de hecho *no* es la palabra que usamos para el concepto "gato"; pero, al pronunciarla, nos da un sonido muy parecido al que hacen los gatos.
Y así, la relación se invierte: usamos las palabras, no para transmitir un concepto abstracto mediante sonidos, sino por su propio sonido. Estas palabras son las [onomatopeyas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22846/13628).

Pensemos ahora en los movimientos del cuerpo. ¿Qué relación existe entre el lenguaje y los movimientos del cuerpo? Pues...

... básicamente ninguna.
**Las palabras necesitan de los sonidos para ser habladas. Pero no es necesario hacer ningún movimiento con el cuerpo para hablar**, más allá de los que hacen la glotis, la lengua, la mandíbula y los labios (y para algunos, ni eso).
Y por el mismo motivo, **aunque hay palabras que al pronunciarlas provocan sonidos concretos, no existen palabras que al pronunciarlas provoquen un movimiento del cuerpo**. La manera más sencilla entonces de transmitir esa idea de movimiento es, simplemente, enunciar la acción: "alzar el brazo".

**Por eso en español no existe ninguna clase de palabras para los movimientos del cuerpo**, similar a las onomatopeyas para los sonidos.

---

NO OBSTANTE...

La única razón por la que no existe tal clase de palabras es que el español, como casi todos los lenguajes, está basado en sonidos. Pero no todos los lenguajes están basados en sonidos. Hay lenguajes que están basados en... movimientos del cuerpo :)

En la [lengua de signos española](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lengua_de_signos_espa%C3%B1ola) (LSE) [se conoce como **signos icónicos**](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/lenguaje-de-signos--0/html/ffbeaf86-82b1-11df-acc7-002185ce6064_6.html) a los signos basados en el movimiento o la forma de lo que se quiere representar.
Por ejemplo, **el típico gesto de llevarse la mano a la boca para significar ["comer"](http://www.sematos.eu/lse-p-comer-2129-es.html) sería un *signo icónico de movimiento***, mientras que el signo para ["anotar"](http://www.sematos.eu/lse-p-apuntar+%5Banotar%5D-3797.html) no lo es (sería un *signo arbitrario*). También sería un signo icónico, en este caso *de forma*, el signo para ["casa"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSZEIGHAQRY).

Otro lenguaje basado en los movimientos del cuerpo: **la [mímica](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PHOa6d2) es lo que hacen los [mimos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PHQnzfs), al imitar los movimientos del cuerpo** en diferentes situaciones para transmitir una idea o contar una historia. Por extensión, se puede llamar "mímica" al conjunto de gestos que usan los mimos.

Me gustaría citar una frase de [una web sobre LSE](http://lsefacil.es/que-es-la-lengua-de-signos/), ya que resalta el paralelismo entre los movimientos del cuerpo y las onomatopeyas:

> Las lenguas de signos no son mímica o una simple representación visual de una lengua oral. Tienen una rica y compleja gramática y un léxico normativizado. ***Decir que la Lengua de Signos es solo mimo equivale a decir que la lengua oral son solo onomatopeyas***.

Por último, otro de los motivos por el que los movimientos del cuerpo se describen mediante frases y no mediante palabras, es que es mucho más sencillo aprender a escribir e interpretar todos de la misma manera 26 letras, que hacerlo con dibujos de cuerpos en movimiento. Por eso la escritura icónica de los egipcios evolucionó a las letras latinas (es un resumen un poco basto, pero sirve).
Sin embargo, desde hace unos cuantos años ya, existe **otro elemento que poco a poco se va integrando en el lenguaje escrito y que también puede usarse para representar movimientos del cuerpo: los [emoticonos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EjqioHD)**.

Y después de casi 5 horas de investigación, me voy corriendo .

Answer (score 5):

Sí, se llaman **gestos**:

> [gesto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JARGBj1)
>   Del lat. *gestus*.
>
> 1. m. Movimiento del rostro, de las manos o de otras partes del cuerpo, con que se expresan afectos o se transmiten mensajes.

También te puede valer [ademán](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0ignGD5).

Comment: Creo que lo que Mike quería saber es si existe alguna palabra para designar los sustantivos que denotan movimientos del cuerpo, así como la palabra "onomatopeya" designa sustantivos que describen o imitan sonidos. Me parece que no. A lo sumo existen "verbos de movimiento", pero nada tan específico como "onomatopeya".

Comment: @Gustavson - Yo todavia no entiendo la pregunta.  Pero se ve interesante.

Comment: @Gustavson no entiendo por qué *gesto* no vale. Aunque *onomatopeya* es distinto ya que se imita un sonido con una palabra; los gestos que se describen en la pregunta no imitan a nada, son más bien convenciones culturales. En cualquier caso creo que *gesto* es la palabra adecuada.