# ¿Existen en español "onomatopeyas" para acciones que no requieren sonidos?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, palabras-raras, comparación-de-idiomas, onomatopeyas

Según una definición, en español "la onomatopeya es una imitación lingüística de una palabra que se asemeja con el sonido que representa", por eso el encomillado en el título.

Pero, hay otra definición que dice:

> Onomatopeya es una palabra que proviene del latín tardío onomatopoeia, aunque su origen se remonta a un vocablo griego. Se trata de la imitación o recreación del sonido de algo en el término que se utiliza para significarlo. *También puede referirse a fenómenos visuales*.

[Onomatopeya](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=esjJXI2vBrW35OUPovuUyAs&q=onomatopeyas&btnK=Buscar%20con%20Google&oq=onomatopeyas&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.1126.2745..3241...0.0..0.636.4011.2-7j2j1j2....2..0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i131j0i131i10.YsDq3d_Mibk)

En otros idiomas, como el japonés, lo más parecido que hay a una onomatopeya hace referencia a acciones que tienen sonido o no. Por ejemplo para murmurar usan ブツブツ (algo similar a "butsubutsu") pero para acciones sin sonidos como el silencio usan シーン (transcrito: "shiiiin") y para mirar fijo usan ジー (algo similar a "yiii")

¿Tenemos en español palabras así? ¿Existen en español "onomatopeyas" para acciones que no requieren sonidos? De ser así ¿cuál sería un ejemplo?

Comment: En euskera hay algunas referidas a la luz: el reflejo del sol, el brillo de las estrellas, etc. En castellano en varios sitios aparece *zigzag* como onomatopeya visual aunque ni el DLE ni otros diccionarios la identifican como onomatopeya

Comment: Me hace pensar en The Sound of Silence por Simon y Garfunkel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La onomatopeya japonesa シーン ("shiin") se usa mucho en el ámbito del cómic para expresar el silencio absoluto, y suele ir acompañada de algún dibujo descriptivo de la escena a representar. Tener una onomatopeya para el silencio no deja de ser contradictorio, pero si lo pensamos la onomatopeya del silencio no es más que la onomatopeya del ruido de fondo que queda cuando quitas todo lo demás. Ahora imagina que estás en Japón en mitad del campo, y no se oye absolutamente nada, has eliminado el ruido de la ciudad, los atascos, las conversaciones, solo quedan... las chicharras.

Las chicharras en japonés tienen su propia onomatopeya en realidad, aunque parecida ("miin"). En todo caso a mí el シーン me recuerda a su sonido. En español tenemos un recurso muy similar, que es imitar el [sonido del grillo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BGNT7m5) cuando todos los demás sonidos se han callado:

> Cricrí.
>   Cri-cri-cri...

Otra alternativa podría ser la onomatopeya del viento soplando, que sería el recurso equivalente a la bola de maleza que pasa rondando cuando todo el resto de la escena se ha quedado quieto. Aunque no viene en el diccionario yo usaría "fuuuu" (el DLE recoge [*fu*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IY1td7T) para el bufido del gato). Una última opción sería usar [*zas*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=cQBzz4w), que en español sería el sonido de un golpe, pero podría representar el sonido de detenerse una persona en seco antes de quedarse quieta y en silencio.

En [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22846/12637) tienes una lista de las onomatopeyas que han llegado al diccionario de la RAE, como ves ninguna se usa para el silencio ni para acciones que no impliquen sonido. De ahí que tengamos que ser creativos.

Si ya nos salimos del diccionario, y nos centramos en acciones que no requieran sonido (más allá de la onomatopeya del silencio en sí), a mí la que se me ocurre es la inglesa [*flash*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=I3gkUNG), que se suele usar para el destello de luz del aparato del mismo nombre y que hoy día no tiene sonido.

Comment: @walen pues sí, pero creo que los puntos suspensivos se usan en reemplazo del "shiin" o similares cuando el silencio se produce por quedarse alguien callado sin saber qué decir (esto es, cuando su discurso se ha visto interrumpido, que es precisamente para lo que sirven los puntos suspensivos). Si la escena no corresponde a este caso, no sé si se usarían los puntos suspensivos.

Comment: Estaba pensando en dormir "zzzz" pero puede ser el sonido de la respiración cuando duermes

Answer (score 3):

No creo que existan las onomatopeyas para acciones sin sonido, después de todo, es la onomatopeya la representación de una acción a través de su sonido.

Y si existiera una del silencio, serían los puntos suspensivos (...), que nos indican que es un silencio intencional y no incidental, muy comúnmente utilizado para indicar pensamientos profundos.

Este es el mismo caso con el "shiin" japones, que se acompaña con algún rasgo evidente para maximizar la expresión de la viñeta.

Por otro lado el "yiiiii" se utiliza como la exclamación de un sonido agudo, muy común para reflejar concentración y no puede ser intercambiado con el silencio.

Que normalmente en español e ingles se representan con el "GIIII!"

El manga en específico tiene su propio sistema de iconografía para representar estados de ánimo, como la burbuja que explota para representar enojo, o las líneas diagonales para representar timidez o tristeza.

A estos se les conocen como códigos, signos y símbolos y son parte de lo que estudia la semíotica.
Los códigos y signos para cosas simples como el silencio y las emociones básicas y los símbolos para ideas e ideales más elaborados.

Answer (score 2):

Pensaba que no, pero al buscar, resulta que existen onomatopeyas de "acciones", que en sí no implicarían sonido:

Aggggggh (expresión de terror)

Bah (expresión de desprecio)

Brrrr (sensación de frío)

Buuu (expresión de abucheos)

Hum… (expresión de duda)

jajaja (expresión de risa fuerte)

jejeje (expresión de risa astuta)

jijiji (expresión de risa contenida)

Mmmm (expresión de sabroso)

Ñam-ñam (expresión de comer)

Uff (expresión de alivio)

Yuuujuu (expresión de alegría desbordante)

Puaj (expresión de asco)

Cof, cof (expresión de carraspeo de interrupción)

Shissst (expresión de pedir silencio)

Muac (expresión de beso)

Sniff, sniff (expresión de llorar)

Zzz, zzz, zzz (expresión de sueño)

Ay (expresión de dolor)

Fuente: https://www.ejemplos.co/50-ejemplos-de-onomatopeyas/#ixzz5mh7C0nYf

Comment: Todas estas onomatopeyas implican un sonido real, desde el "agggh" de terror que es el producido por el grito de aterrorizado hasta el "zzz" producido por el sonido de la respiración del que duerme. La pregunta se refiere a si existe la onomatopeya del silencio, algún "sonido" descriptivo de cuando no suena absolutamente nada, como el "shiiiiin" japonés.

Comment: La del sueño tal vez sea correcta. Hay otras que para mi no califican ni como onomatopeyas de acciones con sonidos. Por ejemplo, buu, es literal lo que uno dice cuando abuchea, no una aproximación. Mmm también, o bah. Y hay varios otros dudosos

Answer (score 2):

Se pueden usar onomatopeyas (que no dejan de ser sonidos) para clarificar acciones que no tienen sonido, y que de otra manera no podrían comunicarse de forma verbal (o incluso escrita, si quieres representar el hecho sin explicarlo en sí mismo, como en una viñeta de cómic).

Por ejemplo, una bombilla hace ruido al encenderse (más bien, el *interruptor* de la bombilla hace ruido la ser manipulado). Asociamos (quizá por influencia del cómic, los dibujos animados o medios similares) la acción de tener una idea con una bombilla que se enciende (sobre nuestras cabezas). En una comversación podrías decir

> Estuve con ese problema un buen rato y de repente, *click*, algo se iluminó en mi cabeza y dí con la solución.

El tener una idea desde luego no produce ruido, pero usamos, por asociación, la onomatopeya de otro hecho relacionado para transmitir la idea.

> Estuve un buen rato pensando y entonces algo hizo *click* en mi cabeza

Es una pequeña trampa donde asocias una acción con otra para transmitir, mediante la onomatopeya o su sonido, una acción o suceso que de otra manera no podrías en un medio dado, como es el verbal.

Otras onomatopeyas que podemos usar por asociación para expresar acciones que no hacen ruido (aparte de los grillos o la planta rodadora [mencionadas por Charlie en su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30318/5481)), serían ruedas de engranajes girando (cuando estamos pensando), "flush flush", por ejemplo, para simular el batir de alas de mariposa Que seguramente hace ruido de algún tipo, pero prácticamente inaudible) o el "tic tac" de un reloj para expresar que estamos esperando (por asociación de "el tiempo pasa" mientras espero).

Answer (score 1):

Se ocurren éstas

Titilar - Definitivamente no implica sonido porque se refiere a un cuerpo luminoso.

Tiritar - Se puede hacer sonido al tiritar pero no es indispensable.

Bamboleo - Indica movimiento.

Tris - Como se explica en [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30641/12572), aunque se basa en un sonido, expresa un concepto que no es un sonido: un tiempo muy breve.

Comment: Esas 3 palabras no son onomatopeyas, sugieres que tienen onomatopeyas? Porque hasta donde sé ninguna de las 3 tiene.

Comment: Mi sugerencia es que son de origen onomatopéyico. Estoy consciente de estas palabras tienen una etimología muy discutida pero hay fuentes que refieren su origen como onomatopéyico. Incluso la RAE sugiere que tiritar y bambolear son de origen onomatopéyico.

Comment: y cuales son las onomatopeyas de las que tienen origen? Porque la pregunta apunta a las onomatopeyas, no a palabras que tengan origen en onomatopeyas, que en si no son onomatopeyas

Comment: Por ejemplo, tintin es una onomatopeya, tintinear es una palabra que tiene origen en una onomatopeya (tintin) pero no es una onomatopeya.

Comment: Juan Corominas, en su diccionario etimológico, califica **tiritar** como onomatopeya sin ahondar más en el origen. Opina también que **titilar** no proviene del latin *titillare(cosquilleo)* sino que es una creación del castellano y proviene de *titar (graznido de un pavo)*. Aunque no califica **bambolear** como onomatopeya, afirma que es de origen expresivo.

Answer (score 0):

These words (including onomatopeia) make up a class of words known as *ideophones* (["ideófonos"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RI1dAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA4036&lpg=PA4036&dq=ide%C3%B3fono)). Indo-European languages in general (including Spanish) are notably pauce in such words.<sup>1</sup> However, the following paper seems to classify some non-onomatopeic words "voz de origan expresiva" as such:

> Conforme a estas muestras, se puede constatar que la “voz de creación expresiva” tiene, según Corominas, varias motivaciones subyacentes: en el caso de *coco*, la voz procede del lenguaje infantil, mientras que una palabra como buche parece haberse plasmado a sí misma, a partir de una correspondencia impresión–sonido. El mismo tipo de explicación se ofrece en el caso de *mocho, boque,* o *boto*. Estas etimologías se basan en el acepto de la idea de simbolismo fonético o iconicidad fonética, concretada en la reproducción en el lenguaje, con la ayuda de los fonemas, tanto de impresiones visuales, acústicas, o táctiles, como de formas físicas (cf. *mocho, boto*); en otras palabras, se presupone la participación activa de la sinestesia en la nacencia del léxico.
>
> - [Las ‘creaciones expresivas’ del *Diccionario crítico etimológico
>     castellano e hispánico* en contexto románico e indoeuropeo. Un nuevo
>     (y a la vez antiguo) enfoque](https://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/RFRM/article/view/61689/4564456548222) (2018)

More concretely, the following suggest there are a few regional ones inherited from neighbouring non-IE languages:

> In the Yucatec Maya lexicon, a significant number of stems are lexicalized
>   ideophones... some lexicalized ideophone have been borrowed as loan into Yucatec Spanish. Their expressive character make them interesting and useful words for speakers to describe or suggest complex event, especially in a language poor in expressives such as Spanish. For instance, the Yucatec Spanish expression *tirixta* is the hispanized form of *tirix ta’* ‘strong diarrhea’ itself constructed on the lexicalized form of the ideophone *tíihri’ix* derived from the root *TIX* ‘rinse, wash out’ and the noun *ta’* ‘stool,’ as in (53d).
>
> - [*Ideophones in Yucatec Maya*](http://www-ailla.lib.utexas.edu/site/cilla5/Le%20Guen_CILLA_V.pdf) (p.16)

Basque has an [extensive lexicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ideophones_in_Basque) of such words, so there may be some loans from there also in basque dialects of Spanish.

---

**Notes**

1. > <sup>Notably, English and Spanish are Indo-European languages, which – it has been claimed – are less iconic than most other spoken languages ([Perniss et al., 2010](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2018.01433/full#B69)).</sup>
   >   <sup>- [*Iconicity in Signed and Spoken Vocabulary: A Comparison Between American Sign Language, British Sign Language, English, and Spanish*](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2018.01433/full)</sup>
2. <sup>[*Ideophones, Mimetics and Expressives*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8nSWDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA163)</sup>