# ¿Cuándo se empezó a usar "zasca" en España?

Tags: españa, sustantivos, interjecciones

Parece que la gran sensación de la [actualización 2019](https://dle.rae.es/contenido/actualizaci%C3%B3n-2019) del DLE ha sido la inclusión de *zasca*:

> **[zasca](https://dle.rae.es/?w=zasca&m=form)**
>
> Voz onomat., imit. del sonido de un golpe; cf. *zas*.
>
> 1. m. coloq. Esp. Respuesta cortante, chasco, escarmiento.
> 2. interj. coloq. Esp. U. para imitar el sonido de un golpe o expresar el efecto de un movimiento brusco. *Me dio otro golpe, ¡zasca! Se volvió y, ¡zasca!, pegó un salto.*
> 3. interj. coloq. Esp. U. para indicar una acción sorpresiva o una intención de escarmiento. *Cuando menos lo esperas, ¡zasca!, te avisan. ¡Zasca!, castigado sin postre.*

Esta palabra, que parece que está de moda últimamente, lleva más tiempo con nosotros del que parece, pero ¿cuánto exactamente? En el CREA aparece en un texto:

> *LIDIA: La música... ¿qué tipo de música?
>
>   FERNANDO: Dulce... suave... cálida...; luego... poco a poco... más viva... más viva... trepidante... un trémolo... otro trémolo... y... al final... ¡zasca!
>
>   LIDIA: Al final... ¡zasca! Bueno,... verás... algo he oído... sí... ¿para qué voy a engañarte?... pero, en fin, nada sinfónico, la verdad.*
>
> Adolfo Marsillach, "Feliz aniversario", 1992 (España).

Y en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España aparece incluso antes:

> *... cuando estaban más descuidadas, un caballero aparecía con un alfiler y, zasca, se lo metía...*
>
> Interviú (Barcelona). 19/10/1978, página 27.

¿Cuánto más antigua podría ser la expresión? ¿Cuándo comienza a aparecer en textos en España?

Comment: Relacinado, sobre _zas_: [Why is it that Spanish people use “zas” to refer to rude, sarcastic, sharp, harsh or funny replies?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22763/1674)

Answer (score 2):

He encontrado una [referencia](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/results.vm?o=&w=zasca&f=text&d=creation&d=1683&d=01&d=01&d=1978&d=10&d=31&t=%2Bcreation&l=600&l=700&lang=en&s=17) ligeramente más antigua en la hemeroteca de la BNE (penúltimo resultado de la página 2):

> ...exportable, pero es un siguiente, los tíos, zasca, hacen un símbolo. El punk en realidad no pedido...

*El País (Madrid. Ed. impresa). 5/3/1978, página 48.*

Esta es la referencia más antigua que encuentro con este significado.

#### Hecho interesante no relacionado (*fun fact*)

Hay algunas referencias más antiguas al término *zasca* en la hemeroteca de la BNE, pero se deben a que [cierto pueblo indígena sudamericano llamaba *zasca* al atardecer](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0005037347&page=19&search=zasca&lang=en):

> Dividían   el   día  y  la  noche  en  cuatro  partes:   *suamena*,      desde  la  aurora   al   medio  día;   *mameca*,      desde   el  medio  día  al  ocaso;  *zasca*,    desde    la  puesta  del  sol  á  media  noche;  *cagui*,    de  la  media  noche   hasta   la  salida  del  sol

*España y América (Madrid). 1/1–31/3/1909, página 19.*

Answer (score 0):

Yo recuerdo haberla empezado a oír más a partir del crecimiento de Twitter España desde 2014 o así, cuando se comenzó a popularizar cada vez más la cultura meme tuitera.

Otra forma de rastrearlo podría ser descubriendo cuándo apareció la sección de "Zascas" de *Zapeando* (un programa de TV que empezó a emitirse en 2013 en la cadena LaSexta).

Creo que debe de tener su antecedente en el "Zas! En toda la boca!" de Peter Griffin, popularizado cuando empezaron a emitir *The Big Bang Theory* en España.

Pero ten en cuenta que esto son experiencias, no investigaciones

Comment: En el texto de la pregunta expongo un texto de 1978 que ya usa la palabra "zasca", así que es bastante más antigua que los programas que mencionas. ¡Bienvenido al sitio, en todo caso!